# Reallocating the size of the array by exceeding the limit of it

Tags: c, arrays, malloc, realloc

I cannot solve the issue. The program has to increase the size of array by the desire of the user. However, it skips the conditions and starts showing the array itself.

```
int main() {
    int *ptr;
    int limit;
    int sum = 0;
    int ans;

    printf("enter the limit of the array\n");
    scanf_s("%d", &limit);
    ptr = (int *)malloc(limit * sizeof(int));
    for (int i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
        printf("enter element %d : ", i + 1);
        scanf_s("%d", (ptr + i));
        if (i = limit) {
            printf("do you want to stop entering?\n");
            printf("\t\t1\t0\n");
            if (scanf_s("%d", &ans) == '1') {
                break;
            } else
            if (scanf_s("%d", &ans) == '0') {
                limit += 5;
                ptr = (int *)realloc(ptr, limit * sizeof(int));
                printf("memory re-allocation is completed succesfully!\n");
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
        printf("\nthis is your %d. element : %d\n", i + 1, *(ptr + i));
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: `if (i = limit)` ==> `if (i == limit)` ... Oh! **and turn on the warnings** and **MIND THE WARNINGS!**

Comment: The return value from `scanf_s` is an integer count, so is not going to be equal to the character values `'1'` or `'0'`.  You need to use `ans` to get the value entered by the user.

Comment: Note that `realloc()` can fail, which it indicates by returning a null pointer.  It is unlikely that your program will run into that in practice with moderate numbers of entries, but well-engineered code checks for such errors and handles the situation appropriately when it occurs.

Comment: If you use `gcc` you can compile with `-Wall -Werror` to enable warning.

Comment: `if (scanf_s("%d", &ans) == '1')..else if (scanf_s("%d", &ans) == '0')...` You only need to `scanf` once and only check `ans` in the else-part.

Comment: Note that `ptr = (int*)realloc(ptr, limit * sizeof(int));` leaks memory if the reallocation fails.  Always use `void *new_ptr = realloc(old_ptr, new_size); if (new_ptr == NULL) { …deal with failed reallocation… } old_ptr = new_ptr; old_size = new_size;` or equivalent (you might record a number of items rather than the byte size; that's fine).

Comment: OT: regarding: `ptr = (int*)malloc(limit * sizeof(int));` and similar statements:  1) in C, the returned type is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  casting just clutters the code, suggest removing that cast.  2) when calling any of the heap allocation functions: `malloc()`, `calloc()`, `realloc()`, always check (!=NULL) the returned value.  If not successful, then call `perror( "malloc failed" );` then cleanup, then call `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`  Note: `exit()` and EXIT_FAILURE are exposed via the statement: `#include <stdlib.h>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `if` statement in your code:

```
if (i = limit)
```

does not compare `i` to `limit`. Instead, it assigns the value of `limit` to `i` then it checks if the result of this expression is non-zero. If it is, the block is entered, otherwise it will be skipped.

`=` is the assignment operator. Use the equality operator `==` to compare two operands.

```
if (i == limit)
```